# Does PHP use the /tmp folder to store POST data when receiving large POST requests?

Tags: php, apache

Recently I noticed some POST requests silently failing to one of my PHP scripts when the POST data was over a certain size (about 12KB or something). Note I was not sending `$_FILE` data, just regular POST data.

After checking the usual settings (`upload_max_filesize` etc.) the only thing which resolved this was to restart the web server.

Then I remembered that earlier in the day I had cleared the system's `/tmp` folder.

1. Does PHP make use of the `/tmp` folder when receiving large POST requests?
2. If so, why did it take a server restart to fix the issue (i.e. why didn't PHP just immediately create new temporary files on-the-fly?)

I'm using php-fpm and httpd if that matters.

Comment: php doesn't do anything like that (it holds the post body in memory afaik), [nginx does though](https://serverfault.com/questions/511789/nginx-client-request-body-is-buffered-to-a-temporary-file) for example. What of relevance is in the webserver logs? If you deleted a folder created on startup by a process, preventing it from writing to that path, that'd explain/answer the "why did it take a server restart to fix the issue" aspect.